# MySQL: Using DATETIME as primary key

Tags: mysql, database-design

My database will be storing a large number of data points, so I am using an unsigned BIGINT as the primary key.

Would it ever make sense to use a DATETIME object as the primary key?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No because it can't be guaranteed to be unique. Stick with BIGINT. You can put a nice index on the DateTime for querying and it will be good enough.

Answer (score 20):

Yes of course it makes sense for a date/time to be a key or part of a key if you need to uniquely identify discrete points or periods of time. I can't say if that applies to your scenario but as a general rule there's no fundamental reason why keys can't be based on time - almost any data warehouse does it.

Comment: A DATETIME can not be used to uniquely identify discrete points in time - it can only be used to identify a discrete *second* in time.

Comment: TehShrike - time precision is always relative. The only question is how much precision you require. In fact I was not answering for the MySql case but for the more general case of basing keys on time. It doesn't matter though because every DBMS has some limit to the precision of time that can be recorded.

Comment: Mysql supports datetime fractions of seconds to 6 decimal places precision. My understanding is many natural keys are more performant . I was hoping for some hard data not irrelevant nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't make sense, as you would be limited to one record per second without any actual reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense if your data comes from a single time-ordered set. Say, a record of financial transactions. If you have multiple data points which naturally occurred at different instants, but have the same timestamp due to rounding, change the low-order bits to discriminate them.

<strike>This is [more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) [problematic](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523) in MySQL than in [other](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) databases, because timestamps are stored with only 1-second precision.</strike> (Edit: as of 5.6.4, MySQL has microseconds precision on time types)

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have multiple observations per second this will fail. For this reason it's probably better not to unless you can guarantee that there will never be more than one point per second.