# Sql Server using DateTime as Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

Hi my questions is similar to:

[MySQL: Using DATETIME as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022579/mysql-using-datetime-as-primary-key)

But I'm specifically interested in Sql Server and I want to approach the question practically with a specific scenario in mind rather than theoretically as in the other post.

I want to store events/actions that users perform. The odds of more than one user performing an action in the same 100ms gap is very low and infrequent collision are acceptable. If I could discretely express 10ms or even 1ms gaps then I'm very happy with the risks.

Thus begs the question, can I use a DateTime as my primary key instead of a unique identifier, because I will be regularly querying the latest 100 events and sorting the events by the time which they occurred.

Comment: If you're always sorting by the event time and rarely/never sorting by the identity, you should leave the identifier on there but create the clustered index on the EventTime column instead of the identifier.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, but it sounds like a very bad idea to me.
If you are really worried about performance, you can use a sequential unique identifier, an auto-incrementing integer, or you can give the DateTime column its own clustered index (recommended).

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to avoid a surrogate key for this (ID/identity column), I would at least combine the datetime column with the user id column for a composite key.  This sounds like a more natural fit for your data.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, use DATETIME2, not DATETIME. You can achieve upto 100 nanosecond precision in SQL Server 2008.

If you sometimes need to record more than one row for a given time, however infrequently, then I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by making the date and time into a key. Important criteria for choosing keys are Familiarity, Simplicity and Stability. On that basis, assuming it does make sense for your requirements, a date and time seems like a sensible choice.

Answer (score 1):

In order for infrequent collisions to be acceptable you really cannot use the timestamp as there will be collisions.

You could code around collisions by using a smart procedure that modifies the datatime slightly, but why bother when an index on the timestamp would suffice and be far easier to implement.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) is informative on precision issues specific to C# however.